# Cannot read property 'name' of undefined in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, material-ui, react-final-form

I am using `react final form` with `material UI` .when I am adding `custom text field or material UI component` I am getting this error
**Cannot read property 'name' of undefined**

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-darkness-uzr2t

```
import React from "react";

export const TextField = props => {
  console.log(props);
  const {
    input,
    label,
    meta,
    required,
    placeholder,
    disabledInput,
    onKeyPress = () => {},
    onInputChange = () => {}
  } = props;
  const id = input.name;
  let { value, ...restProps } = props.input;

  return (
    <TextField error {...input} id={id} label={label} variant="outlined" />
  );
};

export default TextField;
```

Comment: you don't have `input` in your `props` 
try changing two lines to this:
`const id = props.name;
  let { value } = props;`

Comment: You need and adapters in order to use custom components in react final form. Here are adapters in-action: https://codesandbox.io/s/40mr0v2r87